# Заполнить двумерный массив по шаблону

Tags: c#

[image: Шаблон заполнения массива]

Необходимо заполнить массив по шаблону, приведенному выше. С клавиатуры вводятся количество строк и столбцов. Попытки найти циклы, что собирают "уголки", успехом не увенчались, поэтому решил попросить помощи здесь. Вопрос состоит в нахождении самого цикла, что сможет "рисовать уголки".

Comment: двумя вложенными циклами можно заполнить по данномму шаблону. как пробовали сами? или думать лень и нужен просто ответ?

Comment: Пробовал идти от того факта, что заполнение идет только под главной матрицей диагонали, т.е. перед циклами идет условие, связанное с этим. далее пытался вогнать в цикл самую крайнюю левую вертикальную черту, однако следующий цикл, теперь уже горизонтальной черты поставил мозги в тупик.

Comment: Делаете первый цикл n=0..2 общий, в нём можете сделать 4 вложенных, чтобы не запутаться для каждой стороны. Например ky=n..y-n-1. Тут ArrayName[n,ky]=n+1 заполнит левую сторону. По аналогии делаете остальные 3. Можно параллельные стороны заполнять одновременно в 1 цикле, тогда будет только 2 вложенных, а можно по максимальной стороне сделать цикл и заполнить в одном все 4 стороны, просто будет не наглядно и с дополнительными условиями

Answer (score -1):

```
for i = 1 to n
    for j = i to n
        x(j, i) = Min(i, n - j + 1)
    next j
next i
```